# how to call a bat script in jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, tfs-power-tools

Hi I am tring to call a script in jenkins, but that script only
works in the `tfpt.exe` command line. It is the TFS command line. I have
created the scripts with the commands already, only these do not work
with `cmd.exe` which is the usual Windows command line, but only with
the `tfpt.exe` ( Developer Command Prompt for VS2015). How can I specify
that this one should be used, with its path as well I guess?

Comment: You can extend the PATH (depending on what type of build you are using) with the location of the `tfpt.exe` parent dir

Comment: thank you. care to give an example? thanks

Comment: What kind of build are you using? I.e. In pipeline: `withEnv(["PATH=c:\tftp\parent\dir;${env.PATH}"]){ bat "tftp.exe 'command'" }`

Comment: @Rik oh iam using a freestyle project

Comment: Try starting your script with: `set PATH=c:\tftp\parent\dir;%PATH%`